# What is the name of this piece that regulates the flow to the showerhead?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, sink, bathroom-fixtures

When I was replacing an old shower hose, a piece from the tap came off. That piece regulates the flow to the shower head. I am trying to find a replacement, but I am having difficulty doing so since I don't know its name.  What is the name of this piece?

[image: This is the piece I am looking for]

This is the piece I am looking for (on top of shower hose)[image] It's stuck to the old shower hose. When looking on the inside, you can see that it is some sort of valve

[image: This is my sink]
This is my sink

[image: The piece should be inside the inner hole (second from the left) of the sink]
The piece should be inside the inner hole (second from the left) of the sink

Comment: What you are showing appears to be simply a flexible hose that goes to the shower head.  These are usually seen on showers that have a head that can be handheld.  I doubt that you will find a replacement as every one of these I've seen is slightly different.  You will probably be better off just buying a new shower attachment that includes a new hose.

Comment: Guessing on the size and the oring I would say 1/2” straight thread but it is probably an OEM part as most regular fittings do not have flow restrictors built in. You may be able to get a replacement from the manufacturer.